# Programming for Java Card 3 platform in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, javacard

I've wrote programs for Java Card 2.2.2 in Eclipse using [EclipseJCDE](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/) plugin and [Java Card 2.2.2 Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-2.2.2-oth-JPR).

Now I want to write programs for my smart card that is a Java Card 3.0.1 Classic Edition, but I don't have any idea how I can do it!

Can I wrote my programs in Eclipse now or I need a new plugin?

As far as I know I must download a new development kit for this new platform. So I searched [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-2.2.2-oth-JPR). Some where it is mentioned that :

> The Java Card 3 platform consists of versions 3.0, 3.0.1 and 3.0.4 of
>   the specifications and versions 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3 and 3.0.4 of the
>   development kit.

So I downloaded the **Java Card 3.0.1** specification and **Java Card 3.0.3** development kit. But it is not really a development kit! It is a *.jar* file only!

What shall I do with this *.jar* file? Should I import it as library in my project along with the libraries of JC 2.2.2?

Or I must copy it in the *bin* directory of the previous development kit?

I'm really confused about it! Should I add another plugin for Eclipse? Or I must change mu IDE?

Why JC 3.0.3 Development kit is not similar with JC 2.2.2 Development kit?

BTW, I add it to the JAR file libraries in my project, but it contains some weird classes that I didn't see them in JC 3.0.1 API Specifications! And it doesn't contain any framework or APDU or ... class!

What shall I do to be able write programs for Java Card 3.0.1? and how can I convert them to *.cap* file? (As far as I know I can't use the *converter* anymore, Is it right?)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .jar is actually just an installer. You'll have to run it to get the real runtime using `java -jar <file.jar>`. Then you should get the SDK.

Comment: Is there any Java Card platform 3.0 plugin for Eclipse? Can I write programs and convert them to .cap file just like what did for java card 2 ? (right click on my package and clicking on convert in the Eclipse)

Comment: There is of course JCOP, but the tricky part is to get it, it's not open source.

Comment: Anything else? (A free tool). I read the Java Card 3 platform development kit guilde and as I understood, I can write my programs in Net Beans with Java Card **Connected** Edition installed on, and then compile them to .class files and then using _Converter_ of Java Card 3.0.3 **Classic** edition, convert them to .cap files for Java Card 3.0.1 classic edition. Am I right? BTW, Is there any plugin for Eclipse to do it automatically (just like eclipse-jcde)

Comment: Yeah, the 3.0.3 SDK version should be compatible with 3.0.1 classic. I'm not sure about a plugin for Eclipse (that would be an answer I suppose). You could adopt the software that was made available for 2.2.2, the general card structure is not different in any meaningful way, the SDK should be largely identical.

Answer (score 6):

To develop for Java Card target 3.0.1 in Eclipse (on any platform):

1. Get Java Card 3.0.3 development kit (JCDK 3.0.3 implements specification 3.0.1). You can get it [here](https://github.com/martinpaljak/oracle_javacard_sdks/tree/master/jc303_kit). Alternatively you can download it from Oracle web page, but then you will need Windows machine to install .jar and get its contents.
2. Download Java Card 3.0.1 specification (`java_card_kit-3_0_1-doc-spec-rr-15_may_2009.zip`). Extract its contents.
3. In Eclipse right-click on your project "Build Path --> Add External Archives..." and add `lib/api_classic.jar` from the 3.0.3 development kit directory. This will enable code completion and fix potential import errors.
4. In Eclipse right-click on api_classic.jar --> "Properties --> Javadoc location path:" and specify `javacard_specifications-3_0_1-RR/classic/api_classic/` from the 3.0.1 specification directory. This will enable javadoc for Java Card API calls.
5. To convert your project's .class files to .cap files use [ant-javacard](https://github.com/martinpaljak/ant-javacard). Run `ant` from the directory where `build.xml` and `ant-javacard.jar` is located. Here is build.xml example:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project name="Hello World" default="Hello" basedir="."> 
   <target name="jcpro">
   <taskdef name="javacard" classname="pro.javacard.ant.JavaCard" classpath="ant-javacard.jar"/>
   </target>
   <target name="Hello" depends="jcpro">
   <javacard>
   <cap jckit="jc303_kit/" aid="01020304050607080900" output="testjcard.cap" sources="workspace/testjcard/src/testjcard/">
   <applet class="testjcard.JTest" aid="0102030405060708090005"/>
   </cap>
   </javacard>
   </target>
   </project>
   ```

The `build.xml` can also be added under your project in Eclipse.

6. Upload the produced .cap file into the smart card using gp.jar from GlobalPlatformPro:

```
    java -jar GlobalPlatformPro/gp.jar -delete 0102030405060708090005
    java -jar GlobalPlatformPro/gp.jar -delete 01020304050607080900
    java -jar GlobalPlatformPro/gp.jar -install testjcard.cap
```

Comment: this helped me. Thank you very much for your verbose answer

Comment: Really helpful answer, +1.

Answer (score -1):

I install java_card_kit-classic-3_0_5-u4-win32-bin-do-b_109-03_jun_2020.msi in my eclipse, and i can create java card3 project, but it said **An error occurred while creating the Java Card Project. javax/xm/bind/JAXBEception**

Comment: I recommend posting a new question instead of asking a question as a SO answer